# The mail desktop shortcut simply broken on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, email

When you drag the mail icon on the desktop it appears as blank, it was OK before, but changed to the blank icon one day. Here is the gif demo
[image]
Can anyone help to fix?

Comment: Relevant: http://superuser.com/questions/955586/windows-10-blank-start-menu-icons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### I've found [this](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5645-icon-cache-rebuild-windows-10-a.html) article, where are two possible solutions!

---

**Short description the first possible solution:**

1. Download [this](http://www.tenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/63027d1454896567-icon-cache-rebuild-windows-10-a-rebuild_icon_cache.bat) file and save it to your Desktop
2. Close and save everything you have open now
3. Run the .bat file and when the securety warning pop-up click on "Run"
4. Follow the instructions in the Command Prompt and Restart the PC

---

**Short description of the second possible solution:**

1. Close and save everything you have open now and open the Command
   Prompt
2. Copy and Paste each command below (Don't forget to press enter)

   ie4uinit.exe -ClearIconCache

   taskkill /IM explorer.exe /F

   DEL /A /Q "%localappdata%\IconCache.db"

   DEL /A /F /Q "%localappdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\iconcache*"

   shutdown /r /f /t 00

Comment: rebuilding the icon cache did the trick, I've got the nice mail icon back, thank you @Stackcraft_noob!

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a shortcut for Windows Mail on the desktop
2. Open Task Manager
3. Go to the Processes tab, right-click Windows Explorer, click End Task (keep the Task Manager open)
4. Go to File → New Task and write in `cmd.exe`
5. Type in the Command Prompt: `cd %userprofiles%\appdata\local` and press Enter
6. Type `del iconcache.db /a` and press Enter Enter
7. Close the Command Prompt
8. In Task Manager, go to File → New Task and start `explorer.exe`

Rebooting the computer may be necessary.

Comment: This post doesn't helped? Or why im get downvoted?