# Windows 10 & metro apps start menu icons on search

Tags: windows-10, icons, start-menu

I've been having this problem since a few months, it's very similar to this: [Blank start menu icons on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/955586/windows-10-blank-start-menu-icons) but yet a bit different, i of course tried the proposed solutions there but nothing worked so far.

Basically on my start menu all icons are fine and working perfectly, but when i search for a metro app this happens:

[image]

i even tried contacting microsoft's support to no avail, they just suggested to reinstall (which i don't want to do)

If anyone has any idea on how to solve this, i would be extremely grateful

Thank you

update: also tried every solution posted here [UWP icons are missing](https://superuser.com/questions/1283165/uwp-icons-are-missing) with no success

Comment: *"i of course tried the proposed solution there"*  Did you try more than one of the proposed solutions?  There are several of them with multiple up-votes.  You should also try to [reinstall and re-register all of the built-in Windows apps](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3175-reinstall-re-register-apps-windows-10-a.html):  open an elevated PowerShell window and enter `Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}`

Comment: yeah i tried that as well, didn't work, i'm gonna add an "s" and spell solutions instead of solution

Comment: Metro applications don’t exist on Windows 10.  On Windows 10 they are UWP applications.  “It didn’t work” means you successfully ran the command or something else?  Edit your question to clarify your question.

Comment: it didn't work means that i of course ran the proposed solutions/commands and nothing changed, i really don't see what else "it didn't work" could mean in this context, thank you for the clarification about UWP tho, i'll try a google search with the term, maybe something will come up

Comment: @joyrex - I attempted to explain what is confusing about your statement "it didn't work".  It is not clear if the command ran without any errors and simply didn't resolve the problem, or you ran the command, and it generated an error.  I would normally load a VM, to test different solutions, but I can't recreate this problem.  So I am at your mercy to provide all the necessary information to answer your question.  Just to confirm, you have attempted to repair the profile, using the registry modification.